# Is there a way to prove that this function crosses the $x$ axis only twice?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, hyperbolic-functions

I have this function ($x>0$):
$$   f(x)=\left(x^2+2\right)^2 \cosh (x)-\left(2-x^2\right)^2 \cosh (3 x)-\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2      $$
Here is the picture of the function and its first derivative

[image]

I want to prove that this function crosses the $x$ axis only twice. Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @Anand that is a transcendental equation....

Comment: The function divided by $x^2$ is fairly well behaved and has limit $-8.25$ at zero.  Perhaps you can find intervals where it is positive, or negative, that overlap intervals where its derivative is positive, or negative.

Answer (score 2):

Evaluate $f(0.8),f(1)$ and $f(2)$. Then note that the function is continuous, and since $f(0.8) < 0 < f(1)$ and $f(1) > 0 > f(2)$, by the IVT there must be 2 roots.

As is pointed out by @user247327 in a comment below, this demonstrates there must be *at least* two roots. Not clear if you want to prove there are *exactly* 2 roots.

Comment: Sasha1988, do you want to prove that the graph crosses the x-axis "exactly twice" or "at least twice"? gt6989b's argument shows that there must be **at least** two roots, not necessarily exactly two roots.

Comment: @user247327 I need to prove it crosses $exactly-twice$, not more.

Comment: $f(-\infty)=+\infty=f($ sot it will have either no root or even number of roots.

Comment: so the amount of crosses is in $2\mathbb N$. Thats still far from beeing a solution.